# Do multiple shell scripts sourcing a common other script interfere with each other when they modify a "sourced" variable?

Tags: shell-script, variable, parallelism

If I source the same shell script from multiple other scripts, which I run in parallel, and modify a shell variable defined in the sourced script, will the *sourcing* scripts mess up each other's value of that variable?

Example :

- `source.sh`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  some_value=$1+10
  ```
- `file-1.sh`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  source ./source.sh 5
  ./some-script $some_value
  ```
- `file-2.sh`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  source ./source.sh 10
  ./some-script.sh $some_value
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You have as many environment or shell variables `$some_value` as you have processes which define them.

Then if you launch at the same time `file-1.sh` and `file-2.sh` you will have different values since you have different processes. Note that `source` doesn’t create process, the sourced script works with the `file-1.sh` and with the `file-2.sh` process environments.

Answer (score 1):

When you `source` a shell-script, that means the current shell instance is reading the script line-by-line and executing the commands on the spot, as if you had entered them on the command-line (if you are executing the `source` call from the prompt) or as if you had copy-and-pasted them into the script (if you are sourcing from a script).

Therefore, the different shell scripts `file-1.sh` and `file-2.sh` both behave as having a locally defined shell variable that only coincidentally has the same name `some_value` in both cases. Even if you ran the two scripts in parallel, they would not know anything about each other, and so there are no cross-interactions between them - the sub-shell in which `file-1.sh` is running does not know that the sub-shell in which `file-2.sh` is running also happens to have a variable `some_value` defined.

---

As a side note, your attempt at creating an arithmetic expression as

```bash
some_value=$1+10
```

will not have the effect you may imagine. For `file-1.sh` it will yield `5+10` literally, and for  `file-2.sh` it will yield `10+10` literally. In order to perform arithmetic evaluation, you have to place it in an arithmetic expansion, as in

```bash
some_value=$(($1+10))
```

I would recommend checking shell-scripts with [`shellcheck`](https://shellcheck.net), also available as standalone tool on many Linux distributions, to catch syntax (and some logical) errors.